# Skip locked rows for editing using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, cursor

Can I lock a row so that the cursor does not bring it because it is in use by another cursor ?

```
ITable table=GetTable();
ICursor crntCrsr=null;
ICursor secondCrsr=null;
crntCrsr=table.Search(filter,false);

 // This cursor will contain one row. I want to lock it so that if 
var firstRow= crsntCrsr.NextRow();

// now If I use the same statement as above, I will get the same row again.
// I want to skip this row because it is already being processed by crntCrsr
secondCrsr=table.Search(filter,false);
var secondRow= secondCrsr.NextRow(); 

// basically I do not want secondRow to be the same as firstRow
```

Comment: No, ArcGIS does not support row-level locking. Use a single cursor and assign processing from there.

Comment: Thanks Vince,  I was hoping ArcGIS supports this. My current tool could be used by multiple processes at the same time in different threads. Some processes might come before others, so I need to make sure that 2 processes do not grab the same row, or a row that is already being processed somewhere else. a Select state FOR UPDATE statement will solve this issue.

Comment: As stated, your threading should be assigned elsewhere. Your current system is likely to cause failure.

Comment: Instead of *var* firstRow make it *IRow* firstRow then you can skip using if (firstRow.OID == secondRow.OID) secondRow= secondCrsr.NextRow(); https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wt000000 A cursor from an ITable returns IRow objects; I find it best to use the *actual object identifier* rather than the ambiguous *var*.